# Sn(II) compound stereoselectivity in aldol reactions

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, aldol-reaction, stereoselectivity

In "advanced organic chemistry: part B" fifth edition, page:130, the authors state that chiral proline-like additives to Sn(II) compounds can further increase stereoselectivity of aldol reaction. Then they showed how different TS evolve to the observed product

[image]

Wouldn't it be more accurate if the the enolate approached the aldehyde from the aldehyde's Re face not Si. because I find the Si face attack more hindered (at least in the open TS)